# Spring return HttpStatusCode after Jquery/Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have a .jsp where I use jquery/ajax.
I used it to exchange JSON documents which works fine.
Now I just want to return a HttpStatuscode to create a popup if an exchange was successfull.

My Controller function returns type `HttpStatus`.

```
@PostMapping("/setPermissions")
public HttpStatus setPermissions(..) {
    return HttpStatus.OK
}
```

Can anybody tell me if the return Type is correct or do i have to add another annotation?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done like this:

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@PostMapping("/setPermissions")
public ResponseEntity setPermissions(..) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

or

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@PostMapping("/setPermissions")
public void setPermissions(..) {

}
```

Comment: I can't use your first implementation because
1) ResponseEntity is a raw type
ResponseEntity is a raw type. References to generic type ResponseEntity<T> should be parameterize
2)Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder to ResponseEntity

I changed my implementation to:
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> setConsumerPermissions(..)
return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.OK);
but still doesn't work.
Error:
The character encoding of the pure text document was not declared

Comment: @medTech I have updated the answer. I was missing a `.build()`

Comment: Thank you.
I used your answer but still doesn't work. I still got the error with the character encoding missing.
I guess this has to be a jsp/ajax problem.
I am still not shure about my ajax call.
$.ajax({  type:'post',
      url:"${path}/user/setPermissions?id="+Id,
      contentType:' charset=utf-8',
              success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                  alert(xhr.status);
              },
              error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                  alert(data.responseText);
              }
      });

Comment: No there is no reference to spring but there are also no further details.l
It's when I open the browser spec and watch the console.
I did a workaround now and return a String with the code.
But I wouls prefer to return just a code in the response.